# What is the mean of K$2 returning?

Tags: excel

Hi all i am working on Excel i have formula  in my excel sheet i didn't understood what it is it is returning K$2 mean could any body help me please actually i am new to it here i want to know what it is returning means what value we r getting

```
(IF(ISBLANK(K73),1,K$2)*IF(ISBLANK(L73),1,L$2))
```

thanks in  advance

here i need to multiply the value i get and i need  to subtract i will that my self the problem it i don't understood what it is retuning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always using `2` - it's a constant so when you drag a formula down the other addresses will adjust but `K$2` and `L$2` always remains the same.

`K2 = $K$2` and `K$2` so it returns the value that is in your `Range("K2")` or `Cells(2, 11)`

if you are evaluating your formula you can start inside the most nested expression.

`(ISBLANK(K73),1,K$2)` , if `K73` is blank then expression will be `1`, if `K73` is not blank then the value of `K2` will be returned

Answer (score 3):

`K$2` just means the value of cell K2, but the row number (2) is an *absolute* reference not a *relative* reference. For example, if your formula is in cell M73 and you copy and paste it to cell M74, it will update to

`(IF(ISBLANK(K74),1,K$2)*IF(ISBLANK(L74),1,L$2))`

The relative row reference has been updated but the absolute one stays the same. You can also put the $ character in front of the column letter, or in front of both column and row.