# Excel - How to assign a cell value to a variable?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I don't know how to describe it its a bit complicated.

But when I pull cells down I don't want a cell to change like `E2 E3 E4`. I want to make fixed `E2` there. I don't want it to change when I pull down cells.

So do I have to assign it to a variable if yes, how to do it ? :)

Thats my formula;

```
=0+(if(d4="x";d2;0))+(if(e4="x";e2;0))+(if(f4="x";f2;0))
```

I want to make fixed `D2 E2 F2` when I pull cells down but it changes whatever like `D3 E3 F3`.

Thanks.

Comment: =0+(if(d4="x";$d$2;0))+(if(e4="x";$e$2;0))+(if(f4="x";f2;0))

Comment: thanks:) 
it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(D4="x",$D$2,0)+(IF(E4="x",$E$2,0))+(IF(F4="x",$F$2,0))
```

and if your locale are german or some other ones then

```
=IF(D4="x";$D$2;0)+(IF(E4="x";$E$2;0))+(IF(F4="x";$F$2;0))
```

and refer to [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296758/what-is-the-mean-of-k2-returning/19296820#19296820) answer for more details about the `$` dollar sign within formulas.